# how to get number key value from json php

Tags: php, json

i want key_value from json data but don't use loop

```
        $y = "2018";

        $json = '[
                  {"2017":[{"p":"50","v":"55"}]},
                  {"2018":[{"p":"50","v":"55"}]}
                ]';
        $obj = json_decode($json, true);
        if(array_key_exists($y, $obj)){
            return $json[$y]; 
        } else {
            return array_search($y, $obj);
        }
```

return only number 1

Comment: ___NOTE___ `$obj` is an array of objects. That should be all you need to know

Comment: This seems a bit unclear to me what you need? You seem to be already getting what you need with `$json[$y]`

Comment: @LiamG `$json` is a string.

Comment: The problem is that it's an multidimensional array. The functions that OP is using are not meant for a multidimensional array.

Comment: Why is it so important not to use some kind of loop?

Comment: not sure this json format will be very useful for you. For `2018` you need  `$thang = $obj[1][$y]` , ie you need to know not only the key but its position in the enclosing array.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Who said that it is important to NOT use some kind of loop?

Comment: @BasvanDijk See the first line of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $num = array_walk($json, function($a) use ($i) {
        $y = "2018";
        if(isset($a[$y])){
            return $i;
        }
        $i++;
    });
```

return 1

Comment: I thought I'd dropped a sign &

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is your expected answer

```
$y = "2018";
$json = '[
          {"2017":[{"p":"50","v":"55"}]},
          {"2018":[{"p":"50","v":"55"}]}
        ]';
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
return array_column($obj,$y);
```

This will return an array like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [p] => 50
                    [v] => 55
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: It returns nothing

Comment: @BasvanDijk: It will return an array you can execute and print array too if your php version (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)

Comment: This actually requires PHP 7.0.7+ to run properly due to a weird side-effect of the fix to this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72031. See https://3v4l.org/deS1L

Answer (score 0):

Since your json string is as follows when decoded:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2017] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [p] => 50
                            [v] => 55
                        )    
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2018] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [p] => 50
                            [v] => 55
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

`array_key_exists` looks whether the given key exists within the given array. 
`array_search` looks whether the given value occurs within the given array.

Those functions are not able to look into a multidimensional array. You should loop over the array and then execute your `array_key_exists` and/or `array_search` functions.

Comment: There really is no way

Answer (score 0):

ok so I have tried to complete it without using a loop, this may be what you are wanting or maybe not.

```
$y = "2018";

$json = '[
          {"2017":[{"p":"50","v":"55"}]},
          {"2018":[{"p":"50","v":"55"}]}
        ]';
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

function exists( $key, $value, $y )
{
  global $result;
  if( isset( $key[ $y ] ) )
  {
    $result = $key[ $y ];
  }
}
array_walk( $obj, "exists", $y );
var_dump( $result );
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["p"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["v"]=>
    string(2) "55"
 }
}
```

Comment: it did not work ; return null and Notice: Undefined variable: result

Comment: my PHP  5.4 version

Comment: my PHP  5.4 version

Comment: array_walk() is (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: I checked it right now, but I just want a number that returns this value to the is array 1

Comment: return only index